# What is the best way to do french text analysis in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to do text analysis on a french texts to visualise similarities between those texts, the possible class depending on the words that are used.
I ask for your help because I just started working with Python and I would like to know the best way to do text analysis in Python taking into account that my texts are in French ?

**Are there libraries specially designed for french texts ?** The uses would be to clean the data, and further to analyse the data.

I can already :

- Clean: Removed all special  characters, put every word in lowercase and suppressed STOPWORDS
- Tag : It's not optimal on french words (Libraries tested : StanfordPostagger, Tag.pos de NLTK).
- Lemmatize : Not optimal (--) with french words(FrenchLefffLemmatizer,  WordNetLemmatizer)
- Stemming: FrenchStemmer snowball

**What I can't do with French words : pass to singular, pass verbs to the infinitive form...**

Comment: Knowing how severe we are here on StackOverflow, this upvote seems rather suspect to me...

Comment: @vlemaistre https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/476

Comment: Ups didn't think about that, I just wanted to help. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Sorry for the translation problem, this was my first question on Stack and i forgot to translate... Thanks @vlemaistre for your translation help !
I added a few details

Comment: @AliS the question is too broad. Any full-text search engine can handle multiple languages, using language-specific stemmers and word breakers. Most databases have FTS functionality since the 1990s and French was one of the first languages added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacy library and Treetagger tool (that you can use through treetaggerwrapper library) have good french support.

Example using [spacy](https://spacy.io/) :

```
import spacy
nlp_fr = spacy.load('fr_core_news_sm')
text = "J'ai mangé des pommes hier"
tokens = nlp_fr(text)
for token in tokens:
    print(token.lemma_)
```

Prints :

```
je
avoir
manger
un
pomme
hier
```

Treetagger is more difficult to install but [this](https://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) can help you and [here](https://treetaggerwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the documentation of the python wrapper.